# Urn problem where you remove as much balls as the r-th side of a fair dice of n faces tells you

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

This is another problem from David Stirzaker Elementary Probability. As context you have $2n$ balls, $n$ of which are tangerine and the other $n$ are heliotrope. The problem goes as follows:

"A fair die with n sides is rolled. If the rth face is shown, r balls are removed from
the urn and placed in a bag. What is the probability that a ball removed at random from the bag is
tangerine"

The books gives as answer $\frac{1}{2}$ but I'm not sure how to get there. What I've been trying to do is consider the procedure from another problem that's almost identical to this except that there is no fair die and you are only taking $n$ balls instead of the $r$ that indicates this problem, the answer to that problem [is in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3069110/urn-problem-involving-removement-of-half-of-the-balls), it went like this:

$$P(B)=\frac{1}{\binom{2n}{n}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{n-k}{n}\binom{n}{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\right)=
\frac{1}{\binom{2n}{n}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\color{blue}{\frac{n-k}{n}\cdot\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}}\cdot\binom{n}{k}\right)=\\
\frac{1}{\binom{2n}{n}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\color{blue}{\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k-1)!k!}}\cdot\binom{n}{k}\right)=
\frac{1}{\binom{2n}{n}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\color{blue}{\binom{n-1}{k}}\cdot\color{red}{\binom{n}{k}}\right)=\\
\frac{1}{\binom{2n}{n}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n-1}{k}\cdot\color{red}{\binom{n}{n-k}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$

With this in mind what I tried to do is consider that every face in the die has a probability of $\frac{1}{n}$ to show up and to consider every posible value that $r$ can have as follows:

$$P(B)=\sum\limits_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{\binom{2n}{r}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^r\frac{n-k}{n}\binom{r}{r-k}\binom{r}{k}\right)$$

Where you are considering that you choose $r$ balls from the total of $2n$ to remove and you consider each possible $k$ such that in those $r$ balls you removed exactly $k$ tangerine balls. But I'm not sure to how can i get to the $\frac{1}{2}$ answer, so I would appreciate a lot the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let us find the conditional probability of choosing a tangerine ball given that the roll of the die was $r$. I think you will find the proof here is quite similar to the proof you provided in your post.
$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{choose tangerine}\mid \text{roll} = r)
&=\frac1{\binom{2n}r}\sum_{k=0}^r \frac{r-k}{r}\binom{n}{r-k}\binom{n}{k}
\\&=\frac1{r\binom{2n}{r}}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \color{blue}{(r-k)\binom{n}{r-k}}\binom{n}{k}
\\&=\frac1{r\binom{2n}{r}}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \color{blue}{n\binom{n-1}{r-k-1}}\binom{n}{k}
\\&=\frac{n}{r\binom{2n}{r}}\binom{2n-1}{r-1}=\frac12
\end{align}
$$
Since the conditional probability of drawing a tangerine is $1/2$ for every possible roll of the die, it follows that the overall probability is $1/2$. In detail,
$$
P(\text{choose tangerine})=\sum_{r=1}^n P(\text{choose tangerine}\mid \text{roll = r})P(\text{roll }=r)=\sum_{r=1}^n \frac12\times \frac1n=\frac12.
$$

Comment: I kinda understand what you did but for example, why are you taking $\binom{2n}{n}$ in the conditional probability if you're considering the case where you remove $r$ objects from the urn? Why isn't $\binom {2n}{r}$

Comment: @SamHaze Thank you for the feedback, that was a careless error on my part which is now fixed. You said “for example,” Is there anything else unclear?

Comment: I had a few things unclear but i figured out, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

There is no preference for any particular ball to be chosen. Each of the $2n$ balls in the urn is equally likely to come out of the bag at the end of the process. So since half the balls are tangerine, there is a probability of $\frac12$ that a tangerine ball is chosen.

Comment: I had thought about that, but I'm also curious if this particular procedure is right